# Why are there "Welcome to Texas" signs, but similar signs don't exist for other states?

Tags: usa, cultural-awareness, texas

Why does Texas have "Welcome To Texas" sign in Texas border ? But "Welcome to Virginia" or "Welcome to Washington" or "Welcome to Maryland" signs aren't there?

Comment: Probably because you're entering Texas but not Virgina or Washington or any other state?

Comment: im going to guess the sign is paid for by the state and not the federal government.

Comment: All the U.S. states do have "Welcome to <insert state name>" at their borders.

Comment: Something like this one: [Texas](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vQsyFBKQzCI/Tmfg8I7r52I/AAAAAAAAACM/JkbST9V5Cso/s1600/texas_don%2527t+mess+wih+TX.jpg) ?

Comment: I've seen Welcome to Utah, Welcome to Arizona and Welcome to Nevada....

Comment: Some rural roads won't have flashy signs.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I dispute the premise of your question. (All images from a google Image Search for "Welcome to [State Name]")

[image: Virginia]

[image: Maryland]

[image: Washington]

You can find examples for all 50 states at [this site](http://www.elistmania.com/still/50_welcome_signs_from_50_states/) - note however that while all 50 states are represented, that list is far from exhaustive of all the designs and styles that can be found, depending upon which border crossing you're at. Many states will, for example, have much more elaborate signs at the state border along interstate highways, and simpler, less imposing ones on less substantial roadways with lower traffic.

Comment: In addition to this, Wikimedia Commons has a dedicated category https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:State_border_signs_in_the_United_States?uselang=ca with 50 subcategories - one per state.